# Are there eComStation Boot Manager command line tools?

Tags: os2

Are there command line tools for the eComStation Boot Manager, i.e. such that Boot Manager can be configured from a (native) DOS or OS/2 command line to boot into a specific OS without displaying the Boot Manager screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes.

- For the old IBM Boot Manager, there is of course `setboot`.
- For the new Boot Manager in eComStation version 2.1 and upwards, [Air-Boot](http://www.ecomstation.it/ecsoft2/prog.php?progid=871), there is `setaboot` that is in the Air-Boot package.